# SwiftUI - how know number of lines in Text?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a dynamic text, it can be small or large
I what by default show only 3 lines and **only if needed** add "more" button.
When the user tap on this button ("More") - I will show all test.

I ask, **how to know in SwiftUI if text it more of 3 lines or not?**

Answer (score 23):

You can use a `GeometryReader` to determine the width of the text field and then use that together with information about the font to calculate the size of the bounding rect that would be required to show the entire text. If that height exceeds the text view then we know that the text has been truncated.

```swift
struct LongText: View {

    /* Indicates whether the user want to see all the text or not. */
    @State private var expanded: Bool = false

    /* Indicates whether the text has been truncated in its display. */
    @State private var truncated: Bool = false

    private var text: String

    init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }

    private func determineTruncation(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) {
        // Calculate the bounding box we'd need to render the
        // text given the width from the GeometryReader.
        let total = self.text.boundingRect(
            with: CGSize(
                width: geometry.size.width,
                height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude
            ),
            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
            attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)],
            context: nil
        )

        if total.size.height > geometry.size.height {
            self.truncated = true
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text(self.text)
                .font(.system(size: 16))
                .lineLimit(self.expanded ? nil : 3)
                // see https://swiftui-lab.com/geometryreader-to-the-rescue/, 
                // and https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/
                .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                        self.determineTruncation(geometry)
                    }
                })

            if self.truncated {
                self.toggleButton
            }
        }
    }

    var toggleButton: some View {
        Button(action: { self.expanded.toggle() }) {
            Text(self.expanded ? "Show less" : "Show more")
                .font(.caption)
        }
    }

}
```

This is then how it looks for both long and short texts:

[image: Usage example preview]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works for me as of June 2020

Comment: This works great with fixed font sizes, but we want to use a Font object from SwiftUI to determine the font size. However, String.boundingRect wants a UIFont in the attributes. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. I was looking for a way as well to construct a `UIKit.UIFont` instance from a `SwiftUI.Font`, but there just doesn't seem to be a way.

The only thing you could do is to introduce a small abstraction over Font that knows how to create both `UIFont` and `SwiftUI.Font` instances from it? Imho that wouldn't be too hacky, but it will largely depend on your project.

Comment: This is a really good start and inspired me to take it further, and remove the need for a UIFont (see answer). Thanks.

Comment: doesn't work for me on iOS16

Answer (score 17):

Building on the excellent work from bhuemer, this version respects SwiftUI's local Font rather than requiring a hard-coded UIFont. Rather than reading the size of the "full" text using String layout, this renders Text three times: once for real, once with a line limit, and once without a line limit. It then uses two GRs to compare the last two.

```
struct LongText: View {

    /* Indicates whether the user want to see all the text or not. */
    @State private var expanded: Bool = false

    /* Indicates whether the text has been truncated in its display. */
    @State private var truncated: Bool = false

    private var text: String

    var lineLimit = 3

    init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // Render the real text (which might or might not be limited)
            Text(text)
                .lineLimit(expanded ? nil : lineLimit)

                .background(

                    // Render the limited text and measure its size
                    Text(text).lineLimit(lineLimit)
                        .background(GeometryReader { displayedGeometry in

                            // Create a ZStack with unbounded height to allow the inner Text as much
                            // height as it likes, but no extra width.
                            ZStack {

                                // Render the text without restrictions and measure its size
                                Text(self.text)
                                    .background(GeometryReader { fullGeometry in

                                        // And compare the two
                                        Color.clear.onAppear {
                                            self.truncated = fullGeometry.size.height > displayedGeometry.size.height
                                        }
                                    })
                            }
                            .frame(height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
                        })
                        .hidden() // Hide the background
            )

            if truncated { toggleButton }
        }
    }

    var toggleButton: some View {
        Button(action: { self.expanded.toggle() }) {
            Text(self.expanded ? "Show less" : "Show more")
                .font(.caption)
        }
    }
}
```

The following shows the behavior with surrounding views. Note that this approach supports `LongText(...).font(.largeTitle)` just like a regular Text.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let longString = "This is very long text designed to create enough wrapping to force a More button to appear. Just a little more should push it over the edge and get us to one more line."

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("BEFORE TEXT")
            LongText(longString).font(.largeTitle)
            LongText(longString).font(.caption)
            Text("AFTER TEXT")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of preview showing More button for largeTitle text, but no More button for caption text.]

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: This doesn't work with List. It seems List reuses rows and height is not calculated correctly.

Comment: I find this crashes Xcode 12 or 13 beta when it reaches
.frame(height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude) in preview, and I do mean crashes Xcode and unexpectedly quits.
If I change the height to a constant like 1000, it no longer has a problem, but it's hacky. The code seems to work fine in the running app.

Comment: it doesn't work for me either

Comment: doesn't work for me on iOS16

Comment: @Rob Napier what should I do if I want to show (show more/ show less) at the end of text

Comment: Any update on this? Running SwiftUI on iOS 14 and need this feature exactly.

Answer (score 6):

In iOS 16+ it is possible to achieve this with the use of [`ViewThatFits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewthatfits) set as a hidden background of the line-limited text.

This approach also respects the system font size when changed.

```swift
struct ExpandableText: View {
    let text: String
    let lineLimit: Int
    
    @State private var isExpanded: Bool = false
    @State private var isTruncated: Bool? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text(text)
                .lineLimit(isExpanded ? nil : lineLimit)
                .background(calculateTruncation(text: text))
            
            if isTruncated == true {
                button
            }
        }
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        // Re-calculate isTruncated for the new text
        .onChange(of: text, perform: { _ in isTruncated = nil })
    }
    
    func calculateTruncation(text: String) -> some View {
        // Select the view that fits in the background of the line-limited text.
        ViewThatFits(in: .vertical) {
            Text(text)
                .hidden()
                .onAppear {
                    // If the whole text fits, then isTruncated is set to false and no button is shown.
                    guard isTruncated == nil else { return }
                    isTruncated = false
                }
            Color.clear
                .hidden()
                .onAppear {
                    // If the whole text does not fit, Color.clear is selected, 
                    // isTruncated is set to true and button is shown.
                    guard isTruncated == nil else { return }
                    isTruncated = true
                }
        }
    }
    
    var button: some View {
        Button(isExpanded ? "Show less" : "Show more") {
            isExpanded.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can try my solution

```
public struct CollapsingTextView: View {

@State private var isCollapsed: Bool
@State private var textToShow: String
@State private var words: [String]
@State private var lineLimit: Int
@State private var ghostSize: CGRect = .zero
@State private var visibleSize: CGRect = .zero

private let textOriginal: String
private let buttonName: String
private let font: UIFont
private let color: Color

public init(
    isCollapsed: Bool = true,
    text: String,
    lineLimit: Int = 3,
    buttonName: String = "more",
    font: UIFont,
    color: Color
) {
    self.isCollapsed = isCollapsed
    self.textToShow = text
    self.textOriginal = text
    self.lineLimit = lineLimit
    self.buttonName = buttonName
    self.font = font
    self.words = text.components(separatedBy: " ")
    self.color = color
}

public var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .top)) {
        
        Text(textOriginal)
            .font(Font(font))
            .foregroundStyle(Color.clear)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .lineLimit(lineLimit)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    let _ = defineGhost(geometry)
                    Color.clear
                }
            )
        
        Text(textToShow + (isCollapsed ? "... \(buttonName)" : ""))
            .font(Font(font))
            .foregroundStyle(color)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    let _ = defineVisible(geometry)
                    Color.clear
                }
            )
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation {
            isCollapsed = false
            textToShow = textOriginal
        }
    }
}

private func defineGhost(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) {
    let total = self.textOriginal.boundingRect(
        with: CGSize(width: geometry.size.width,
                     height: geometry.size.height),
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: font],
        context: nil
    )
    ghostSize = total
}

private func defineVisible(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) {
    let total = self.textToShow.boundingRect(
        with: CGSize(width: geometry.size.width,
                     height: geometry.size.height),
        options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [.font: font],
        context: nil
    )
    visibleSize = total
    
    if (ghostSize.height > 0 && visibleSize.height > 0) && (ghostSize.height < visibleSize.height) {
        changeVisibleText(ghostHeight: ghostSize.height, visibleHeight: visibleSize.height)
    }
}

private func changeVisibleText(ghostHeight: CGFloat, visibleHeight: CGFloat) {
    guard isCollapsed else { return }
    if visibleHeight >= ghostHeight {
        // trim text
        let trimmedWords = words.dropLast()
        words = Array(trimmedWords)
        textToShow = trimmedWords.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using eja08's idea I made a custom overlay:

```
struct MoreButton: ViewModifier {

    @State private var isTruncated = false
    @State private var size: CGSize = .zero
    let text: String
    let action: () -> ()

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(calculateTruncation)
            .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                if isTruncated {
                    moreButton
                }
            }
    }

    private var calculateTruncation: some View {
        ViewThatFits(in: .vertical) {
            Text(text)
                .hidden()
                .onAppear {
                    isTruncated = false
                }
            Color.clear
                .hidden()
                .onAppear {
                    isTruncated = true
                }
        }
    }

    private var moreButton: some View {
        Button("MORE", action: action)
            .bold()
            .foregroundStyle(.primary)
            .background(.background)
            .background(
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                        self.size = proxy.size
                    }
                }
            )
            .background(
                LinearGradient (colors: [.clear, Color(UIColor.systemBackground)], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
                    .offset(x: -size.width)
            )
    }

}

extension View {
    func moreButtonOverlay(_ text: String, action: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
        modifier(MoreButton(text: text, action: action))
    }
}

#Preview {
    VStack {
        let text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
        Text(text)
            .lineLimit(2)
            .moreButtonOverlay(text) {
                // Do something
            }
    }
}
```

[image: light mode]

[image: dark mode]

Answer (score 0):

I had same thing to do so I was searching for a solution. I will think about a better solution but I think my solution is more clean and covers a little bit more cases. Having in mind that I might reuse this I begun with creating ViewModifier:

```
struct TruncatedTextModifier: ViewModifier {
@Binding var isTruncated: Bool
let lineLimit: Int

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .lineLimit(lineLimit)
        .background(
            content
                .lineLimit(lineLimit)
                .background(GeometryReader { displayedGeometry in
                    ZStack {
                        content
                            .background(GeometryReader { fullGeometry in
                                Color.clear.onAppear {
                                    isTruncated = fullGeometry.size.height > displayedGeometry.size.height
                                }
                            })
                    }
                    .frame(height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
                })
                .hidden()
        )
}}
```

Creating this as a ViewModifier and using content makes sure that all of the modifiers (such as fonts, alignments and so on) used on this Text component will be applied to the nested ones. Personally I don't like using .modifier() so I created an extension:

```
extension View {
    func truncatedText(isTruncated: Binding<Bool>, lineLimit: Int) -> some View {
        modifier(TruncatedTextModifier(isTruncated: isTruncated, lineLimit: lineLimit))
    }
}
```

Extension is made to View because of modifiers. So now whenever I wanna truncate any Text component in my App I can do it this way:

```
        Text(text)
            .bodyMediumRegular(color: .neutral0) //my other typography extension
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .truncatedText(isTruncated: $isCommentTruncated, lineLimit: lineLimit)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example:

```
struct TextDemo: View {

    @State var moreText = true

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Button(action: { self.moreText.toggle()} ) { Text("More") }
            Text("hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello")
                .frame(width: 300)
                .lineLimit( moreText ? 3: nil)
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: hey
it a good idea, but it did not give me real indicators to know the numbers of lines in my text. I found a way to know number of lines! i don't want show "More" if not need!

Comment: So what way do you find?

Comment: I don't find yet.